# Refresh JFace TreeViewer without flicker

Tags: jface

I have prepared a outline view for the content of the editor.
Data is displayed as a TreeViewer.
But when we refresh it the whole tree flickers.

Is there any way to achieve tree refresh without whole tree refreshing? I would want to refresh all the nodes after the edited node.

Answer (score 1):

Use`TreeViewer.refresh(element)` to refresh just 'element' and its children.

If you just want to update a particular element you can use `TreeViewer.update(element, null)` or use `TreeViewer.update(element array, null)` to update an array of elements. This does not handle changes in the tree structure.

You can also use `TreeViewer.add(parentElement, childElement)` to tell the viewer about a new child element, there are also various `remove` methods to remove elements.

Comment: update does not work in my my case and I am using refresh(element) already.I have not used add yet.So let me try it and see how it works...thanks

Comment: I had to update most of the nodes with new information based on the content change in editor.Thus refresh of multiple nodes is not avoidable but after optimizing code logic flickers is not prominent as before. But thanks greg for your continual support.

Answer (score 1):

```
treeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(false);
//Refresh your tree
treeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(true);
```

The above code will help you out!